# Design general model inside ignition (Citadel or Fortress)

Tags: gazebo-model, ignition-fortress, gazebo-ignition, ignition-citadel

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How do you design models just like this: https://app.ignitionrobotics.org/fuel/models

I wanted to start, but I'm not sure where. I know the cheating way only by using Blender and import it to .DAE or .OBJ. That's it.

How do you guys do this?

Update #1 in Feb 16 1:09 PM EST:
Oof! I used Blender and exported .obj AND .dae file format.

Now it couldn't load them. I must have done something wrong. I was able to load dae from this link, but not my own file. This has to be from the program

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27836/design-general-model-inside-ignition-(citadel-or-fortress)/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2022-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Found, it's the special blender script. The tutorial is available here: [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vd0YYC5ROk6MPMOKjW5itqq75i41R3NcYcKld-Sgi4g/edit#gid=0)

---

Originally posted by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) with karma: 87 on 2022-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0